# Adding attribute to markdown NSAttributedString goes out of bounds

Tags: swift, markdown, nsrange

I have user input which can contain markdown or not. I want to show the user input on screen with rendered markdown. For some reason, **I want to add my own static string which does not contain markdown to the end of the user input in the blue color**.

It worked when I didn't used markdown. My guess is that `Data` is changing the original range, which makes my code invalid.

This is my code:

```
let trailing = "I MUST be blue :)"
let newString = "some *user* input" + trailing
let data = newString.data(using: .utf8)!
let replacedMessageText = try! NSMutableAttributedString(markdown: data)

replacedMessageText.addAttribute(
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,
    value: UIColor.blue,
    // Here I want to find the range of my trailing static text
    range: (newString as NSString)
        // This line is probably wrong...
        .range(of: trailing, options: .backwards)

)
```

This crashes with this error:

> "NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds"

I did check out the methods on `Data`, but none of them returns an `NSRange`. How can I make my code work? Markdown does not support colored text :(.

Comment: `newString` has two additional characters, the MarkDown tags: `*`. So its length is different from `replaceMessageText.length`. If you print `replaceMessageText.string`, you'll notice it, so the `range` is wrong

Comment: Instead, what about creating one `NSAttributedString` for each part (trailing, and the other one), with the desired effects, and then append them?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create a new blue attributed string out of `trailing`, and *then* append it to `newString`?

Comment: @Larme I didn't knew this was possible! It worked :) I would be happy to accept it as an answer if you post it, you were just a few seconds quicker than Sweeper

Comment: The main issue, would be though if you have a tag startnig on "start", and one ending on "trailing", they won't be interpreted... Just in case.

Comment: @Larme That's fine. My trailing text will never contain tag/markdown attributes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity of the explanation, let's do a little change:

```
let trailing = "I MUST be blue :)"
let newString = "some *user* input" + trailing
```

->

```
let trailing = "I MUST be blue :)"
let leading = "some *user* input"
let newString = leading + trailing
```

The issue is that `newString` is different from `replacedMessageText.string`, because the Markdown tags (here it's `*`) have been interpreted and removed. You can see it by printing `replacedMessageText.string`.
So in your case, the range of the trailing is wrong (it's length is too big), hence the error.
If you had reversed `trailing` and `leading`, it would have worked with your sample case, but you would have seen part of `leading` colored.

Instead, you can do:

```
let final = NSMutableAttributedString()
let leadingAttrStr = try NSAttributedString(markdown: Data(leading.utf8))
let trailingAttrStr = NSAttributedString(string: trailing, attributes: yourBlueAttributes)
final.append(leadingAttrStr)
final.append(trailingAttrStr)
```

As a note (it's not your case, but if someone encounter the issue), if you have a Markdown tag that starts on `leading` and ends on `trailing`, it won't be rendered.

Unrelated:
`newString.data(using: .utf8)!` can be done with `Data(newString.utf8)`, no need to force unwrap.

Comment: You don't need the Data. Just do: `let leadingAttrStr = try NSAttributedString(markdown: leading)`